# Coldfusion 2021 loads white pages for cfm files

Tags: coldfusion

Here's some small info about the server:

Windows Server 2019
Coldfusion 2021
IIS 10

```
<!--- Dump out the server scope. --->
<cfdump var="#SERVER#" />

<!--- Store the ColdFusion version. --->
<cfset strVersion = SERVER.ColdFusion.ProductVersion />

<!--- Store the ColdFusion level. --->
<cfset strLevel = SERVER.ColdFusion.ProductLevel />
```

I've added everything in IIS, CGI, ISAPI Filters and Restrictions and I have all the handlers. I do have `.cfm` in the default documents. Issue I keep seeing on my test page is just a blank white screen. This was my test file coding:

What might be the issue and why am I just getting a white screen of death on all my cfm pages?

Thanks

Comment: Check your logs in `cfusion\logs`. Is there anything in the out or error log that seems relevant?

Comment: coldfusion-error has zero from today. coldfusion-out just say that it ran the client purge. HTML files load fine. CFM files goto a white screen. Doesn't matter if I'm on the server or doing it by IP address. I can load the admin page with the port. Everything in wwwroot comes up white only.

Comment: does it work differently if you specify the file name instead of depending on default document?  so `http://example.com/index.cfm` instead of just `http://example.com/` .

Comment: Is there an application.cfm/cfc page that might be blowing up?

Comment: Adding the extension doesn't do anything different. There's a application file, but not in the root so it wouldn't see that.

Comment: I can also see cfm files on the server if I use localhost. If I try it with the ip address it goes white, but only for cfm files.

Comment: Have you run the wsconfig file to set up ColdFusion to run with IIS?

Comment: @TRose suggestion is where I'd start.  You can find the wsconfig utility in C:\ColdFusion2021\cfusion\runtime\bin if it is a default installation.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a disconnect between the app engine and IIS.  You should look into commandbox: https://commandbox.ortusbooks.com/setup/installation

Also has BonCode connectors for IIS.  https://commandbox.ortusbooks.com/embedded-server/external-web-server

Comment: How is this an answer? There are plenty of CF installations that work perfectly fine without using an intermediary like Commandbox.